# Ruby - FileUtils.cp deletes file and fails

Tags: ruby

I am trying to copy a file in ruby using `FileUtils#cp`

Unfortunately, Ruby is deleting the file and then is unable to copy it because it is missing.

Is this a known bug or something I am doing wrong with the cp method.

```
src = "/var/tmp/myfile"
dest = "/usr/bin/myfile"

FileUtils.cp(src, dest)
```

It always complains that src file is missing but when I check it has been deleted.  If I recreate the file and set permissions to 777 the file is present, after running the script it is gone and the copy fails

Comment: How did you run this? Have you tried it just from an `irb` session? I ran your example (without your quote type for `dest` ;)) and it worked OK for me.

Comment: Could something earlier in your code be deleting the file? This works for me too.

Comment: FileUtils#cp should not delete a file. Also you might require write permissions to move to /usr/bin, you could try with root privileges

Answer (score 0):

Place the following in a copy_myfile.rb, then run with: *sudo ruby copy_myfile.rb*

```
require 'fileutils'


src = "/var/tmp/myfile"
dest = "/usr/bin"

FileUtils.cp(src, dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It seems to work for me in Ruby 1.9.3:

my file permission: -rw-rw-r--

require 'fileutils'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> FileUtils.cp 'test.txt', 'text1.txt'
=> nil

The file does get copied.
```